# Why can't I login to StackOverflow.com on my BlackBerry?

Tags: support, openid, login, blackberry

I have a BlackBerry Curve 8330 and I am unable to login to StackOverflow.com, Why? I spend several hours a week on StackOverflow.com on the BlackBerry but cannot vote, ask or answer questions. I use the Google OpenID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which browser are you using, the built-in?  Have you tried [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/mini/)?

Comment: I am using the built in browser, haven’t even considered using another for some reason.

Comment: Well... That was quick - Worked like a champ. You the man!

Comment: **Opera** saves the day once more.

Comment: @random: You're thinking of Oprah, you fool!

Comment: @Pesto: I didn't know you were a game butchered into a movie.

Comment: @voyager: Yes.  I'm awesome, and Uwe will punch anyone who disagrees with that fact.